# Are the Stack Exchange blogs aggregated somewhere?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, blog

Would be nice to have a single RSS feed for all the various stackexchange blogs, now that we have more than one.

- Is there an aggregate URL or RSS where the blog posts can be read at?

Yes, one could maintain their own list of RSS feeds coming from here, but I suspect that more blogs will be developed over time for the various sites, and it would be nice to have a single location where the feeds will be published or aggregated and updated as new blogs come online.

Comment: Even better yet, add them to the `/sites` method in the API.

Answer (score 6):

We do now!  The main page at Blog Overflow lists recent posts from each blog.

http://blogoverflow.com

---

**Edit:**

An rss feed is now available here as well:  http://blogoverflow.com/feed/network

Comment: I may be daft, but I don't see an RSS feed on that page that contains the posts from all of them - it appears I still have to sign up for each one individually?

Comment: @AdamDavis Still working on a combined RSS feed.

Comment: Ok, I'm not going crazy then.  Thanks!

Comment: I was just thinking how great it would be to have a combined feed earlier today!